# admingenerator configuration error

Tags: symfony, admin-generator

i'm trying to use admin generator with symfony to generate the back office of a web site.

i'm experiencing troubles.

here is my generator.yml (will change some names for confidentiality)

```
generator: admingenerator.generator.doctrine
params:
    model: Company\Bundle\projectBundle\Entity\Oeuvre
    namespace_prefix: Company
    bundle_name: Bundle\projectBundle
    fields:
      titre:
        help: If you want to see this content on you website


builders:
    list:
        params:
            title: List for Bundle\projectBundle
           display: [ titre ]
            actions:
                new: ~
            object_actions:
                edit: ~
                delete: ~
    filters:
        params:
            display: [ titre ]
    new:
        params:
            title: New object for Bundle\projectBundle
            display: [ titre ]
            actions:
                save: ~
                list: ~
    edit:
        params:
            title: "You're editing the object \"%object%\"|{ %object%: YourModel.title     }|"
            display: ~
            actions:
                save: ~
                list: ~
    show:
        params:
            title: "You're viewing the object \"%object%\"|{ %object%: YourModel.title }|"
            display: ~
            actions:
                list: ~
                new: ~
    actions:
        params:
            object_actions:
                delete: ~
            batch_actions:
                delete: ~
```

i get the error Opps an error occurred in your configuration. If you're in prod try cache:warmup

but i'm not ind production environnement and warming cache does not work.

Can someone help?

ty

Comment: Try to clear your cache anyway, regardless of your environment. And then - execute `app/console cache:warmup --env=dev` for dev environment

Comment: I leave the dev for admin generator was too complicated for no result, i used sonata admin instead, was far more simple,

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in your configuration file. Problem is yours bundle depth. Current version of AdminGenerator don't work with "prefixed" bundle. Move your bundle from: `Company\Bundle\projectBundle\` to `Company\projectBundle\` scheme.
I know that AdminGenerator documentation page says that your bundle scheme is correct, but still, this not working. Just change Bundle depth.